# How to get boxed citations and references but colored,unboxed \hrefs

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing

It seems that if I change from boxed links to coloured links using the `\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,true}` command from the `hyperref` package, this has a global effects on all types of links, be it link, cite or URL.

I like my links and cites default red/green boxed, but I don't like how the blue boxes in my bibliography are, and would like to change the, *and only them*, to blue text. Can this be done? I use `\href` in my bibliography like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
 %\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue} Don't want this because will change 
 %links and cites too
\begin{document}

 \begin{thebibliography}
  \bibitem{some}
  \href{http://some.url}{Some Ref}
 \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Whereas links and cites are just using the `\ref{}` and `\cite{}` commands and the global `hyperref` effect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a workaround.

You can declare the following hyper setup locally in the bibliography

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
```

Also define a new command `\hrefblue`

```
\newcommand{\hrefblue}[2]{%
  \href{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
}
```

and use it instead of `\href` inside the bibliography.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\hrefblue}[2]{%
  \href{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Citing}\label{sec:first}

In section \ref{sec:first} we cite \cite{some}.

{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{some}
  \hrefblue{http://some.url}{Some Ref}
 \end{thebibliography}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `colorlinks` from false to true; but you can change the colors if `colorlinks` is set to true.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  %allcolors=black,% all colors are black
  urlcolor=black,% only links are black
}

\begin{document}

\href{http://u.v}{AB}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem{some}
 \href{http://some.url}{Some Ref}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the desired result for the `\href{}`s in the bibliography but with your code I lose the green and red in text boxes, around `\ref{}`s and `\cite{}`s, that I would like to keep.

Comment: @user23112 Then, use `urlcolor=black` instead of `allcolors=black`.